# Can OAuth access tokens be used as a public ID?

Tags: security, oauth

My application is essentially a stateless proxy that converts some data fetched from a service into a different format and serves it to the user on-the-fly. Since the data is not confidential, the only method of authentication will be a large, random URL. Nevertheless, the OAuth access token I'll need to store in order to fetch the data does provide some `write` features, which I'd like to avoid leaking.

My question is whether is it safe to use the access token as a public identifier on the URL and just keep the `secret` key protected, or if I should generate random IDs and link them to the token internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [OAuth 1 spec](http://oauth.net/core/1.0a), access tokens are passed in plaintext (with a signed request) when receiving them and when accessing shared resources with them. Thus using them as a unique identifier shouldn't increase your risk profile at all for an attack as long as you don't leak either of your secrets.

That said, having control over the format of your URLs might be worth the little trouble it is to link the two together. The IDP may have a bug at some point that you don't expect with the format, length, or uniqueness that could hurt you down the road.